# How to fix http_parser deprecated warning in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I recently update my angular project from anycodings_angular the 11 to 12 version and I face this error

[DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: anycodings_angular Access to process.binding('http_parser') is anycodings_angular deprecated. (Use node --trace-deprecation anycodings_angular ... to show where the warning was created)

Comment: What version of node do you have? I changed from 12 to 14 and the error disappeared, I hope it helps you. Regards

Comment: I downgrade the version of typescript from 4.8.0 to 4.1.0 the error disappeared thank you Mr Carles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrade node version will work for me

```
nvm use 14.20.1
ng serve
```